# In how many ways can 3 distinct numbers fill 6 blanks (each repeated exactly twice)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, decimal-expansion

I have a basic knowledge of permutations and combinations but using different approaches to this problem lead me to different answers.
Basically, there are 6 blanks and 3 distinct digits a,b, and c. All three of them occupy 2 blanks. For example, some possible combinations are:

1. a a b b c c
2. a b c a b c
3. a b c c b a

Please mention the approach used and why the approach is logical and the others are not.

Edit: My Approaches:-

1. We can first fill the 2 a's in any of the 6 blanks using 6C2 (as both are same). Then we can fill the 2 b's in any of the the remaining 4 blanks using 4C2. Then we can multiply them (there is no need to fill up c's as 2C2 is 1). The answer comes out to be 90.
2. We can take the a's ,b's and c's as a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 and find the number of permutations. That comes out to be 6P6 = 720. Since we a1 and a2 are same(similarly b1 and b2), we divide by 2 to get 360 (avoiding repetition).

Edit2:
Upon seeing the comments, I realized that in approach2:

1. a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
2. a2 a1 b1 b2 c1 c2
3. a1 a2 b2 b1 c1 c2
4. a2 a1 b2 b1 c1 c2
5. a1 a2 b1 b2 c2 c1
6. a2 a1 b1 b2 c2 c1
7. a2 a1 b2 b1 c2 c1
8. a1 a2 b2 b1 c2 c1

are same. So, I should divide by 8 to get 90. So, is 90 the correct answer?

Comment: Why don't you show us your attempts?

Comment: This is not a do my homework for me site. Please show your work.

Comment: "*but using different approaches to this problem lead me to different answers... why the approach is logical and the others are not*"  What approaches have you tried specifically?  Why do you believe they give different answers?

Comment: approaches shown in edit

Comment: Remember that this is a new contributor! Be nice! Notice that approaches have now been added. Cheers!

Comment: "*we divide by $2$ to get 360*"  and this division by two was in reference to the duplication of the $a$'s.  Now... do that for the duplication by the $b$'s as well so divide by $2$ again... and then divide by $2$ a third time for taking care of the $c$'s.  You get the same answer of $90$.  Both approaches are correct, you just didn't divide by $2$ enough times.  Each instance of needing to divide by $2$ needs to be individually handled.

Comment: is that needed? wouldn't one division suffice? @JMoravitz

Comment: @DS: One division is not enough. You can swap each pair independently.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Your last comment would work well as an answer.

Comment: No, one division is not sufficient.  The shepherd's principle loosely states that if you overcount a scenario such that each outcome was counted exactly the same number of times, you can correct your count by dividing by the amount you counted each outcome.  Here, you counted $aabbcc$ eight times.  Once as $a_1a_2b_1b_2c_1c_2$, again as $a_2a_1b_1b_2c_1c_2$, *a third time as* $a_1a_2b_2b_1c_1c_2$ and so on... You divide by the number of times you counted each scenario, which here was many more than just two times... you counted it eight times, $2^3$.  Similarly for all other outcomes.

Comment: The lesson is that even for the first part, you should have written down the expression in full, $^6C_2*^4C_2*^2C_2$, then you might not have drawn into error for the second case, $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$

Comment: is 90 the correct answer then?

Comment: DS, that has been confirmed more than once in the comments. What appears wrong to you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second approach is what needs to be corrected. First approach is correct.

Imagine that you have two systems that you put the variables:
$$
a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2
$$
through:

1. Permute all six variables $\implies 6!$
2. Flip a coin for each pair $x_1,x_2$ (independently) deciding whether to swap $x_1,x_2$ or not $\implies 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$

So the answer is:
$$
\frac{6!}{2\cdot2\cdot2}
$$
which gives the same answer you get by using combinations:
$$
6C2\cdot 4C2\cdot 2C2
$$